# detailed understanding of netstat -an output on linux

Tags: linux, netstat

I tried to look for a good doc on netstat especially for the options -an but cannot find anything detailed enough.

example 1:

tcp 0 126 android.home:58797 par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net:https ESTABLISHED

what is par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net? it is not a domain name? nslookup returns: Can't find par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net: No answer

example 2:

tcp 0 0 2a01:cb1d:192:e100:f167:9ba7:494f:61fa:45634 par21s03-in-x14.1e100.net:https ESTABLISHED

what is 2a01:cb1d:192:e100:f167:9ba7:494f:61fa:45634?

Comment: Hostname that the IP address reverse-resolves to. IPv6 address.

Comment: is example 2 a v6 address? what about example 1? is it the reverse resolved v6?

Comment: Ignacio, I re-phrased my Q. could you get back to me? many thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are correct.

par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net is the product of a reverse-lookup. Https is what netstat calls port 443 when you don't use -n (which is usually correct). `No answer` means there's something wrong with your local network configuration; nslookup couldn't contact your dns server. Here's my result:

```
>nslookup par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net
Server:  router
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Name:    par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net
Address:  2a00:1450:4007:817::200e
```

The two timeouts before the ipv6 output probably means there is no ipv4 address under that hostname, which is not surprising as hostnames like that tend to exist just to give the address a placeholder to resolve to. This is common practice for hosting sites that might have multiple more "normal" domain names on each ip that shift around.

2a01:cb1d:192:e100:f167:9ba7:494f:61fa is an IPv6 address. 45634 is a port.

Furthermore, since it appears from your tags that you're running linux, I suggest the `dig` command instad of nslookup whenever possible. There's almost always more useful info. You can also specify which server to contact with the @ parameter:

```
$dig @8.8.8.8 par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31757
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;par10s34-in-x0e.1e100.net. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
1e100.net.      59  IN  SOA ns3.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 174338493 900 900 1800 60

;; Query time: 97 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 02 14:01:43 MST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are reversed resolved IPv6 with the port information.

On IPv4 the result would look like this:

> tcp4  0     0  192.168.0.149.50818    stackoverflow.co.https
>   ESTABLISHED

because IPv6 will not fit, it is abbreviated in the format of:

> xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:portNum

netstat is long deprecated for years, and for most common purposes shouldn't be used anymore.

Today you should use ss instead. This displays the full IP address, but will wrap beyond the width of an 80 column terminal.